# Translate informal math expressions into predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I'd like to ask for some help with my HW. I have a signature (=, +, *) over $\Bbb{N}_{>0}$
and I need to translate some statements. I've already figured out predicates for "<", "$x$ is prime" and a couple of others, but I've stuck with these two:

1. "$x$ is $n$th prime number"
2. "$x$ is 5 raised to some power"

Main problem in (2) is how to express exponentiation in terms of predicate logic. And as for (1) I have 2 ideas: 1) count prime numbers below $x$ and compare this number to $n$ 2) run predicate recursively on next prime below $x$. But, again, I don't know how to express it properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help answer the first part of your question. This may not be the most elegant solution, however. We can define a family of predicates $\operatorname{num}_{\leq} (\phi,n)$ for each unary predicate $\phi$ and $n > 0$ true whenever the number of $x$ satisfying $\phi$ is less than or equal to $n$. This is done as follows.

$$\begin{align}
  \operatorname{num}_{\leq} (\phi,1) ~\equiv~ &
    \exists x_1\forall y(\phi(y) \rightarrow y = x_1)\\
  \operatorname{num}_{\leq} (\phi,2) ~\equiv~ &
    \exists x_1 \exists x_2 \forall y (\phi(y) \rightarrow (y = x_1 \vee  y = x_2))\\
  \operatorname{num}_{\leq} (\phi,3) ~\equiv~ &
    \exists x_1\exists x_2\exists x_3 \forall y (\phi(y) \rightarrow (y = x_1 \vee y = x_2 \vee y = x_3)) \\
  \vdots & ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots\\
  \operatorname{num}_{\leq} (\phi,n) ~\equiv~ &
   \exists x_1\ldots\exists x_n\forall y(\phi(y) \rightarrow (y = x_1 \vee \cdots \vee y = x_n))\\
\end{align}$$

Let $\operatorname{prime} x$ be the predicate true if $x$ is prime and false otherwise. For each number $x$, we have the predicate $\phi_x(y) \equiv \operatorname{prime} y \wedge y < x$ true whenever $y$ is prime less than $x$ and false otherwise. If you have abstraction notation available, $\phi_x$ can be written $\lambda y ~ . ~ \operatorname{prime} y \wedge y < x$, which is slightly easier to work with. In either case, the point is that we have a unary predicate. Now we can define the family of predicates $\Phi(x,n)$ true whenever $x$ is the $n$th prime number recursively as follows.

$$\begin{align}
    &\Phi(1,1) \\
    &\Phi(x,n) ~ \equiv ~ \operatorname{prime} x \wedge \operatorname{num}_{\leq}(\phi_x,n-1) \\
  \end{align}$$

For the second problem, recall that $n^m = n \times \cdots \times n$ ($m$ times) whenever $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers. Assuming that you can construct a predicate $\operatorname{exp}(n,m,z)$ true whenever $n^m = z$ and false otherwise, you can test whether a number $z$ is $5$ raised to a power $n$ by testing whether $\operatorname{exp}(5,n,z)$ is true. To this end, it may be useful to recall the recursive definitions of addition, multiplication, and exponentiation, as the predicates in question can be constructed from these.

Comment: By the way, the answer to this question really depends on the kinds of theorems you have available for constructing predicates. For instance, can you construct the predicate corresponding to every primitive recursive function? If so, then Giorgio Mossa's answer is probably more appropriate (you want to find a primitive recursive function that counts the number of $n$ that $\operatorname{prime} x$ is true of using a construction of sequences, then obtain the corresponding predicate).

Answer (score 1):

For what I remember this is a not so easy task in order to codify exponetiation and prime sequences one need to use [Gödel's $\beta$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function) which is a corollary to reminder theorem.

Hope this helps.